# Upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 in ASUS X200CA

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, asus, oem

I have an noteboook ASUS X200CA with Ubuntu 12.04 factory preinstalled.

I would like to update the operating system but I'm afraid it is not working properly, consume more resources than my computer can support or have problems with drivers.

Could someone tell me if the new Ubuntu on this computer working properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the Acer website there are some variations on the specifications, some details would help. 
Anyway, even with the lowest performance hardware, I believe it can easily run the latest LTS release.

In the worst case scenario, you can install a lighter desktop enviorment like lxde, xfce or mate.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the Live CD before proceeding with the upgrade... But I'm still afraid to mess up my notebook

Comment: Don't worry, you'll be fine ^^